# how to get sum of columns in nhibernate linq

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

How should I write query like that:

```
SELECT SUM(c2) sum_c2, SUM(c3) sum_c3, SUM(c4) sum_c4 FROM tableT1 WHERE c1 = 'blablabla'
```

using NHibernate (Linq or QueryOver or Criteria)
to get one-dimensional array of sums?

Comment: Could you try some attempt inspired by doc here http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#querycriteria-projection? if it will fail, show the issue..I'd suggest

Comment: you can find QueryOver examples with aggregations here http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/12/17/queryover-in-nh-3-0.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
tableT1.Where(t=>t.c1=="blablabla")
       .GroupBy(t=>1)
       .Select(g=>new{sum_c2=g.Sum(x=>x.c2),sum_c3=g.Sum(x=>x.c3),sum_c4=g.Sum(x=>x.c4)});
```